# Contact Form 7 from adding paragraph and break tags to HTML emails

Tags: php, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm trying to stop Contact From 7 from adding paragraph and break tags to HTML emails but can't figure it out. About 4 blank paragraph tags are added at the beginning of the email and two at the end.

[This question](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-auto-and-tags) brings up the same issue, and the fix is said to have come in a recent update but I have the most recent one and no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

well if you updated and it didn't work, try doing the fix manually

as per this [user](http://wordpress.org/support/profile/alhadis)

> "The solution I came up with was a serious hack, but there was no other way around it short of editing the plugin's core code. Just stick this somewhere in your theme's functions.php and it should work:"

```
    add_filter("wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced", "suppress_wpcf7_filter");
function suppress_wpcf7_filter($value, $sub = ""){
    $out    =   !empty($sub) ? $sub : $value;
    $out    =   strip_tags($out);
    $out    =   wptexturize($out);
    return $out;
}
```

hope it helps - otherwise if you are really helpless u might have to roll back to an older version of contact form. Version 2.2.1 doesn't seem to have this problem while version 2.3 has it

Comment: I tried that fix yesterday and again today with no luck.

Comment: @carson tried using an older version of contact form ?

Answer (score 1):

I came to the conclusion that new lines (enter's) in the textarea are being converted to html line breaks (br's).

So if I put the input on the same line as the label, it shows correctly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with the contact form plugin. You may look at the plugin source files to see if there are extra
`<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [David Garcia](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8315/contact-form-7-from-adding-paragraph-and-break-tags-to-html-emails/13621#13621),
in the textarea where you compile your form, any new line is converted to a 
 tag.

the paragraphs instead are automatically created by CF7 in rendering the forms.
You've just to reset css to p tags inside the form.

Comment: Nope, I had a css reset. Extra blank paragraph tags were being added somewhere out of my control. I ended up making my own form and sending it hah.

Answer (score -1):

Open the "classes.php" file in the CF7 plugin's "includes" folder and uncomment the following line (number 550) like so ...

```
//$body = wpautop( $body );
```

Hope this helps (you too)!

TIP: Minify your HTML-Email-Content with a HTML-Minifier - just to be safe ;)

Comment: Modifying the core files directly is not a good practise.